# How to create a button to move back and forth in JavaScrtipt

Tags: javascript, arrays, navigation

Good afternoon, everyone.

I'm a newbie in JavaScript, in general in coding. I want to create a "simple" app to move back and forth in a group of texts. With my little knowledge, I could get here, but it didn't work. any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
document.getElementById("botonatras").addEventListener("click", next);


function next () {
var array = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
 
var currentText = 0;
var textMax = 3; 
  
  currentText = (currentText + 1) %textMax;
  
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText;
  
  
}
```

```css
.demo {
  
  height: 200px;
  width:300px; 
  background-color:lightblue; 
  font-family:tahoma; 
  text-align:center; 
  font-size:18px; 
 
}

.boton{
  width:200px; 
  height:50px;
  border:solid;
  border-radius:5px; 
  background-color: rgba(255,90,18,0.5); 
  border-color:red; 
  color:white; 
  
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Aplicacion para realizar lecturas de aplicacion.</p>
<button id="botonatras" class ="boton">Atras</button>
<button id="myBtn" class ="boton">Adelante</button>

  
<p class = "demo" id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With each call function next () internal variables are created again and currentText always to be zero;

Comment: Define the variable currentText at a level above.

Comment: why have you not defined a click-listener for myBtn?

Comment: I deleted my answer, because @Smiranin was faster :) But you should move variable currentText into the global scope in your case - outside next function scope.

Answer (score 1):

I did a three things to your code:

1. moved `currentText = 0` and the declaration of `array` outside your `next` function's scope and into the global scope.
2. moved the part that displayed the new text into its own function
3. called the display function when the page loads with `window.onload`

```js
document.getElementById("botonatras").addEventListener("click", next);

var currentText = 0;
var array = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
function display () {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array[currentText];
}
function next () {
  var textMax = 3; 
  
  currentText = (currentText + 1) % textMax;
  
  display();
}

window.onload = function () {
  display();
}
```

```css
.demo {
  
  height: 200px;
  width:300px; 
  background-color:lightblue; 
  font-family:tahoma; 
  text-align:center; 
  font-size:18px; 
 
}

.boton{
  width:200px; 
  height:50px;
  border:solid;
  border-radius:5px; 
  background-color: rgba(255,90,18,0.5); 
  border-color:red; 
  color:white; 
  
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Aplicacion para realizar lecturas de aplicacion.</p>
<button id="botonatras" class ="boton">Atras</button>
<button id="myBtn" class ="boton">Adelante</button>

  
<p class = "demo" id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could also change the value of `textMax` to `array.length` instead of `3` in case you ever add or remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable currentText at a level above

```js
document.getElementById("botonatras").addEventListener("click", next);
var currentText = 0;

function next () {
var array = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
 

  var textMax = 3; 
  currentText = (currentText + 1) %textMax;
  
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText;
  
  
}
```

```css
.demo {
  
  height: 200px;
  width:300px; 
  background-color:lightblue; 
  font-family:tahoma; 
  text-align:center; 
  font-size:18px; 
 
}

.boton{
  width:200px; 
  height:50px;
  border:solid;
  border-radius:5px; 
  background-color: rgba(255,90,18,0.5); 
  border-color:red; 
  color:white; 
  
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Aplicacion para realizar lecturas de aplicacion.</p>
<button id="botonatras" class ="boton">Atras</button>
<button id="myBtn" class ="boton">Adelante</button>

  
<p class = "demo" id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```